# Why does the frame (trivialization) not affect the type of connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, connections

I am following pages 72 and 73 in Griffiths and Harris. Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and let $E \to X$ be a complex vector bundle. Then a connection $D$ is uniquely (locally) determined by a frame $\{e_i\}$ and a connection 1-form $\theta_{e}$. Let $\{f_i\}$ be another frame. Say the two frames are related by $e_i = \sum_j g_{ij} f_j$.Then the connection 1-form $\theta_{f}$ is given

$$
\theta_f = dg g^{-1} + g \theta_e g^{-1}.
$$

We can decompose the complex cotangent bundle as $T^*X = T^{*\prime}X \oplus T^{*\prime \prime}X$, which are the holomorphic and antiholomorphic pieces, respectively. Thus we can write any connection $D$ as $D = D^{\prime} + D^{\prime \prime}$ where $D^{\prime}: \mathcal{A}^0(E) \to \mathcal{A}^{(1,0)}(E)$ and $D^{\prime \prime}: \mathcal{A}^0(E) \to \mathcal{A}^{(0,1)}(E)$. Locally, the connection 1-form $\theta$ is just a matrix of 1-forms. So $D^{\prime}$ would look like

$$
D^{\prime}\vert_U = (\partial \vert + \theta^{(1,0)}) \vert_U
$$

and similarly for $D^{\prime \prime}$. Your $\theta^{(1,0)}$, for example, would be a matrix of $(1,0)$-forms. My question is, wouldn't the change of frame (change of gauge) change what types of forms you have in your connection 1-form? So how could you ever have a decomposition $D = D^{\prime} + D^{\prime \prime}$? If you change the frame then you would generically pick up some forms of every type from the $dg$ term for the new connection 1-form.

So is the decomposition really dependent on the frame? So then if I say, $\nabla$ is a connection of type $(1,0)$, am I implicitly assuming a choice of frame? And maybe with another frame if is not a connection of type $(1,0)$?

Comment: We're considering holomorphic frames here, so the $g_{ij}$ are holomorphic.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, so for that frame, the $g_{ij}$ are holomorphic and you get a (1,0)-type. But my question is, for a general frame, would it still be of type (1,0)? I don't think so. Just further down the page, it talks about a unitary frame producing a connection 1-form which is skew-hermitian, which means it would be type (1,1) as it would have to have both (1,0) and (0,1)-forms. I guess that's my question - is "type" gauge invariant?

Comment: No, as you yourself have made explicit, type is not in general gauge invariant. But notice that the type of the *curvature* form is invariant, as it transforms just by $\Omega\rightsquigarrow g\Omega g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin! I really appreciate it. It was one of those things that I was either correct, or really misunderstanding something. So why do we even talk about type if it depends on the frame? Don't we only want to deal with things that are gauge-invariant?